# What the weird files '!' and 'export' are and where do they come from?

Tags: file

I have a MacBook which was recently bought and macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Sometimes the weird files named '!' and 'export' are being created in some random directories, for example in my home directory or in others. The files are 0kb both and have such permissions and owner:

-rw-r--r-- alx(my user) staff

What application creates such files and why? I'm tired of deleting these files from everywhere.

Comment: Take a look at the opensnoop command to see if you can catch the process next time it creates files like that. It'll probably be a command like `sudo opensnoop 2>/dev/null | grep 'result$'`

Comment: I've found that this files are being created immediately when I launch Terminal from the folder's path. And the opensnoop command shows many node.js processes touching hundreds of files, but 'export' and '!' are not among them.

Comment: Then you need to look in what are the shell startup files as these are the ones executed on terminal start

Comment: @Mark thanks a lot, this advice was helpful and I've found what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the .bash_profile file and found this lines:

```
> export GOPATH=$HOME/go
> export PATH=$GOPATH:$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
> !
```

It looks like I made a mistake when I ran console command during GO installation. I've removed this '>' symbols and now everything is ok.